# Integrating AnkhSVN with a VS project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, ankhsvn

I've downloaded [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) to use for version control. I'm also using [Codesion](http://codesion.com/) for my repository.

Probably a silly question, but how do I get it to work with an existing project? Basically, how can I set the repository URL for my project and then start using AnkhSVN to check in/out changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have it enabled in VS first (Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> plugin selection)

Connect your project to it via File -> Subversion -> Change Source Control (pick your project)

Their [documentation](http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/com.collabnet.doc.anksvn_001/action/ankh_getting_started.html) is pretty good also.

Answer (score 2):

From http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/com.collabnet.doc.anksvn_001/action/ankh_getting_started.html:

1. Open the project in Solution Explorer.
2. From the File menu in Visual Studio, select Subversion > Change Source Control .
3. In the Change Source Control window, select the row containing your project or solution, and click Connect.
4. Click OK.